# Circles ,analytic geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

An line defined by $ax+by+c=0$ goes through the center of the circle $x^2+y^2+2x-4y+1=0$ and the same line is tangent to the circle $x^2+y^2-2x=3/5$. What are the values of $a,b$ and $c$?
Can any body give me a hint that how to approach this

Comment: Please describe any attempt you have made to solve this problem yourself

Comment: The center is $A=(-1,2)$. By [Joachimthal's notation](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml) $s_1^2=s_{11}s$ or $(x x(A)+y y(A)-(x(A)+x)-3/5)^2=(x(A)^2+y(A)^2-2x(A)-3/5)(x^2+y^2-2x-3/5))$ which factors as $-4 \; \left(x + 3 \; y - 5 \right) \; \frac{3 \; x + y + 1}{5}$ defines the tangent pair.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland That should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Once you’ve found the center of the first circle, this becomes a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/219298/265466 and many other similar questions here. Note, by the way, that there are two distinct such lines, but for each there is in infinite number of values for $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $ax+by+c=0$ is equivalent (without the case of a vertical line) to: $y=mx+q$. By the tangency conditions, I have: 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
(x-1)^2+y^2=\frac8{5}
\\ y=mx+q
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Substituing $y=mx+q$ in the first equation, I obtain: $x^2(m^2+1)+2x(mq-1)+q^2+\frac3{5}=0$. Because the circle and the line have to be tangent, the discriminant has to be equal to $0$, so: $$4(m^2q^2-2mq+1)-4(m^2+1)(q^2-\frac3{5})=0$$
To solve this, I can use the condition on the line $y=mx+q$, in fact it's the same as: 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{12}{5}m^2-8mq-4q^2+\frac{32}{5}=0
\\ q=m+2
\end{matrix}\right.$$
The first equation becomes: $$\frac{12}{5}m^2-8m^2-16m-4m^2-16m-16+\frac{32}{5}=0$$ or in other words: $$48m^2+160m+48=0$$ Taking the discriminant, I obtain: $$m=\frac{-160\pm\sqrt{160^2-4\cdot48^2}}{2\cdot48}=-3 \lor-\frac{1}{3}$$
From this: $q=-1$ and $q=\frac53$. The two lines are: $$y=-3x-1 \rightarrow y+3x+1=0$$  $$y=-\frac13x+\frac53\rightarrow3y+x-5=0$$
There are only two tangent lines from a point to a circle, so there aren't any other lines in the form $x=k$.

Comment: Be careful. You can’t write $ax+by+c=0$ in the form $y=mx+q$ if the line is vertical. You haven’t ruled out that possibility yet when you rewrite the equation in this way.

Comment: @amd: now it's correct.

Comment: Indeed. The OP asked for a hint, though, not a complete solution.

Comment: @amd: I have written what I know about this problem.